# True by accident (and therefore not amenable to proof)

Tags: co.combinatorics, soft-question

The graph [reconstruction conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture) claims that (barring trivial examples) a graph on n vertices is determined (up to isomorphism) by its collection of (n-1)-vertex induced subgraphs (again up to isomorphism).

The way it is phrased ("reconstruction") suggests that a proof of the conjecture would be a procedure, indeed an algorithm, that takes the collection of subgraphs and then ingeniously "builds" the original graph from these.

But based on some experience with a related conjecture (the vertex-switching reconstruction conjecture), I am led to wonder whether this is something that is simply true "by accident". By this I mean that it is something that is just overwhelmingly unlikely to be *false* ... there would need to be a massive coincidence for two non-isomorphic graphs to have the same "deck" (as the collection of (n-1)-vertex induced subgraphs is usually called).  In other words, the only *reason* for the statement to be true is that it "just happens" to not be false.

Of course, this means that it could never actually be proved.. and therefore it would be a very poor choice of problem to work on!

My question (at last) is whether anyone has either formalized this concept - results that can't be proved or disproved, not because they are formally undecidable, but just because they are "true by accident" - or at least discussed it with more sophistication than I can muster.

EDIT:  Apologies for the delay in responding and thanks to everyone who contributed thoughtfully to the rather vague question. I have accepted Gil Kalai's answer because he most accurately guessed my intention in asking the question.

I should probably not have used the words "formally unprovable" mostly because I don't really have a deep understanding of formal logic and while some of the "logical foundations" answers contained interesting ideas, that was not really what I was trying to get at.

What I was really trying to get at is that some assertions / conjectures seem *to me* to be making a highly non-obvious statement about combinatorial objects, the truth of which depends on some fundamental structural understanding that we currently lack. Other assertions / conjectures seem, again, *to me*, to just be saying something that we would simply expect to be true "by chance" and that we would really be astonished if it were false.

Here are a few unproved statements all of which I believe to be true: some of them I think should reflect structure and others just seem to be "by chance" (which is which I will answer later, if anyone is still interested in this topic).

(1) Every projective plane has prime power order

(2) Every non-desarguesian projective plane contains a Fano subplane

(3) The graph reconstruction conjecture

(4) Every vertex-transitive cubic graph has a Hamilton cycle (except Petersen, Coxeter and two related graphs)

(5) Every 4-regular graph with a Hamilton cycle has a second one

Certainly there is a significant chance that I am wrong, and that something that *appears* accidental will eventually be revealed to be a deep structural theorem when viewed in exactly the right way. However I have to choose what to work on (as do we all) and one of the things I use to decide what *NOT* to work on is whether I believe the statement says something real or accidental.

Another aspect of Gil's answer that I liked was the idea of considering a "finite version" of each statement: let S(n) be the statement that "all non-desarguesian projective planes of order at most n have a Fano subplane". Then suppose that all the S(n) are true, and that for any particular n, we can find a proof - in the worst case, "simply" enumerate all the projective planes of order n and check each for a Fano subplane. But suppose that the length of the shortest possible proof of S(n) tends to infinity as n tends to infinity - essentially there is NO OTHER proof than checking all the examples. Then we could never make a finite length proof covering all n. This is roughly what I would mean by "true by accident".

More comments welcome and thanks for letting me ramble!

Comment: Can't one ask the same question about any hard conjecture?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the question "Has anyone has formalized this concept?" will produce an interesting answers. Probably this is not the case and the answer is simply "No: no one has formalized that concept". On the other hand, asking for a list of examples of similar-sounding conjectures (i.e. things that are true by accident - Goldbach's conjecture being the prototypical example) might be more fruitful. If you decide to change the question in the way I suggest, then please don't forget to make it community-wiki.

Comment: @Gjergji: There exist hard conjectures that look quite unlikely, at least at first sight. On the other hand, there exist hard conjectures that look excessively plausible.

Comment: Assuming the conjecture is true, one could computably reconstruct the original graph from the subgraphs by brute force - enumerate all the graphs on $n$ vertices and then eliminate them one at a time if they do not have the correct collection of subgraphs. So the truth of the conjecture would imply the existence of the procedure, but that procedure only works because the conjecture is already known to be true, and the procedure itself would exist even if the conjecture is false, although in that case the procedure doesn't do what it is supposed to do. 

Comment: Perhaps, when you try to formalize the concept "true by accident", you arrive at the concept "true but formally undecidable"? At least I am having difficulty seeing what the distinction between the two might be. 

Comment: What sort of graphs are we talking about? Directed, with loops, with multiple edges? I am asking out of idle curiosity.

Comment: It is truly fascinating how all the answers interpret your question in radically different ways...

Comment: @Andrej: The reconstruction conjecture is false for directed graphs.  I've usually seen it stated for simple graphs (no loops or multiple edges) though I suspect that this distinction may not matter much.

Comment: @Mark: "true by accident" could be interpreted as "true but not amenable to a satisfying human proof." I don't know if this is what the OP means, though. 

Comment: Well, the last paragraph has: can't be proved or disproved, but not formally undecidable. If we interpret "can" ideally, like most here seem to, then the desired formalisation is simply $\bot$. But for most values of "can", I can not always find a witness to a true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence!

Comment: @Carl: And the procedure could be made to always work, in the sense of either reconstructing the graph or refuting the conjecture. (And of course it's infeasible anyway.)

Comment: It's conceivable that the shortest possible proof (in some specified system, say HOL light) of the conjecture is 17241 pages long and involves examination of 3261 cases of special configurations of large subgraphs with various obscure properties.  In that case I would say that the conjecture is 'true by accident' even though it is provable.

Comment: @Neil: Suppose the shortest possible proof of some theorem involves case-by-case checking of the list of finite simple groups, but there is a longer "conceptual" proof.  Does this make the theorem "true by accident"?  I wouldn't say so.  Neither the length of the proof nor the number of cases one needs to check counts decisively in my mind.  "Obscure" properties may become less so the more you familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea that the length of the shortest proof of S(n) tends to infinity as n tends to infinity. But consider P(n) = "there is no PA proof of 0=1 of length at most n". For any n, PA proves P(n), but the proofs get longer and longer. Moreover, PA doesn't prove ∀n P(n). On the other hand, I would say that ∀n P(n) is true for a reason; namely that the natural numbers exist. If you buy this argument, then sometimes things are true for a reason, but they're still not amenable to proof, because our methods of proof suffer from an intrinsic limitation.

Comment: Why should something that is true by accident be *therefore* not amenable to proof?  I can buy that the two things often occur together, but not that the first implies the second.  For example, it is surely, in any reasonable sense, only true by accident that my name is what it is, but nonetheless I can prove easily that that is my name.

Comment: I'd prefer "evidently true" over "true by accident" to put the emphasis on the limited ressources that are available for finding counter examples or for disproving the conjecture because of the length of such a proof.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a very interesting (yet rather vague) question. Most answers were in the direction of mathematical logic but I am not sure this is the only (or even the most appropriate) way to think about it. The notion of coincidence is by itself very complicated. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coincidence ). One way to put it on rigorous grounds is using probabilistic/statistical framework. Indeed, as Timothy mentioned it is sometimes possible to give a probabilistic heuristic in support of some mathematical statement. But its is notorious statistical problem to try to determine  aposteriori if some events represent a coincidence.

I am not sure that (as the OP assumes) if a statement is "true by accident" it implies that it can never be proved. Also I am not sure (as implied by most answers) that "can never be proved" should be interpreted as "does not follow from the axioms". It can also refers to situations where the statement admits a proof, but the proof is also "accidental" as the original statement is, so it is unlikely to be found in the systematic way mathematics is developed.

In a sense (as mentioned in quid's answer), the notion of "true by accident" is related to mathematics psychology. It is more related to the way we perceive mathematical truths than to some objective facts about them.

Regarding the reconstruction conjecture. Note that we can ask if the conjecture is true for graphs with at most million vertices. Here, if true it is certainly provable. So the logic issues disappear but the main issue of the question remains. (We can replace the logic distinctions by computational complexity distinctions. But still I am not sure this will capture the essence of the question.) There is a weaker form of the conjecture called the edge reconstruction conjecture (same problem but you delete edges rather than vertices) where much is known. There is a very conceptual proof that every graph with $n$ vertices and more than $n \log n$ edges is edge-reconstructible. So this gives some support to the feeling that maybe vertex reconstruction can also be dealt with.

Finally I am not aware of a heuristic  argument that "there would need to be a massive coincidence for two non-isomorphic graphs to have the same 'deck'" as the OP suggested. (Coming up with a convincing such heuristic would be interesting.) It is known that various graph invariants must have the same value on such two graphs.

Comment: I have accepted this as best matching the spirit of my question; additional comments are in the "Edit" above.

Comment: I'm reminded of Problem 3c in Chapter 3 of Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*: "Let $f(n)$ be the number of non-isomorphic $n$-element posets.  Let $P$ denote the statement that infinitely many values of $f(n)$ are palindromes when written in base ten.  Show that $P$ cannot be proved or disproved in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory."  The bit about formal unprovability is, in my opinion, a red herring.  I think Stanley is just saying that he thinks that if $P$ is false (which it surely is), then it is false by accident.

Comment: This is a good example. We do not expect "hidden structures" in the sequence f(n), or, more importantly in the sequence of primes, or even in the writings of Shakespeare, but we dont expect that we will be able to refute their existence either. 

Comment: It occurred to me today that this question is closely related to another MO question, [Knuth's intuition that Goldbach might be unprovable](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27755). [Knuth](http://www.ams.org/notices/200203/fea-knuth.pdf) gives Goldbach's conjecture as an example of a statement that is "just, sort of, true because it can't be false. ... So it might very well be that the conjecture happens to be true, but there is no rigorous way to prove it."

Comment: Regarding Gil's suggestion that a statement might admit a proof, but the proof also seems "accidental," see Derek Holt's [comment on an answer to another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438925/results-from-abstract-algebra-which-look-wrong/438927#comment1132083_438927), where he expresses the feeling that Ore's conjecture might be "true by accident" even though we have a proof.

Comment: I made a comment on Holts comment which I deleted but now feel comfortable making again. There are no such things as accidents in math. Every coincidence supports a deeper explanation but we just might not have the machinery to explain such coincidences at the moment. The classic example that comes to mind is the Heegner numbers. Those would have seemed to be almost integers by accident until class field theory was invented. The “by accident” moniker therefore is more appropriately phrased as “by accident w.r.t our current tools”

Comment: Or to put it more succinctly, What seems “by accident” or a coincidence to us today will seem “obviously, the only way it could have ever been” tomorrow

Answer (score 39):

Apart from your specific example, the idea of
truth-by-accident has been studied in the context of formal
first-order languages, which includes the language of graph
theory, and in his dissertation, Kurt Gödel proved
that the statements that happen to be true in all models of
a first order theory $T$ are exactly the statements that
are provable in $T$. This is his famous [completeness
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).

Thus, any statement expressible in the first-order theory
of groups that happens to be true in all groups will be
provable from the group axioms, and any statement
expressible in the first-order theory of graphs that
happens to be true in all graphs will be provable from the
axioms of graph theory.

Your statement, however, does not seem to be expressible
directly in the language of graph theory, since it also
uses the concept of cardinality and of subgraphs, so the
completeness theorem does not apply directly to it for the
language of graphs. Rather, it is a statement of number
theory, and the relevant models for this case would include
all the standard and nonstandard models of arithmetic.

So the relevant conclusion would be that if the statement
were not provable in the first-order [Peano's axioms
PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), then there
is a nonstandard model of arithmetic having a bad
(pseudo)finite graph.

But the particular form of the statement means that it has
complexity $\Pi^0_1$, which means it is a universal
statement quantifying over the natural numbers, and if any
such statement is independent of PA, then it is true, because if it is true in any
model, then because the standard model is an initial
segment of all the others, it follows that it must be true
in the standard model and hence true. This level of
complexity is the same complexity as many of the
interesting independent statements, including consistency
statements.

---

Incidentally, this seems to be my 500th answer on mathoverflow. It's been a lot of fun, and I've surely learned a lot of mathematics!

Comment: @Joel: I confess that I don't understand how this answers the OP's question.  Are you saying that there aren't any statements that are true by accident?

Comment: Congrats on your 500th!

Comment: Timothy, yes, I am arguing that for statements in a first-order language, the (profound) fact that true-in-all-models is the same as provable means that there is no accidental truth. A statement in the language of graph theory is true in all graphs if and only if it is provable from the axioms of a graph. So we don't need another distinction besides provable, negated-provable, and independent. In the case of statements of arithmetic, such a view is intimately connected with a considerations of nonstandard models of arithmetic, but I maintain that it still answers the question.

Comment: Joel, I freely admit to not being an expert in model theory, so please excuse this question.  Why can you not move the "accident" to the construction of the models?

Or, to put it another way, let P be a statement we want to prove.  It might be the case that we can simply prove P.  It might be the case that we can simply prove not(P).  It might be the case that we can easily construct a model where P is true, and another model where P is false, thus showing that P is independent.  However, aren't there other cases?  For example, what prevents the existence of a model where (continued...)

Comment: ... we cannot tell whether or not P is true.

To give a concrete example, take a model sufficiently complex enough so we can express the statement P="The Riemann Hypothesis" and ask whether it is true in the given model.  What prevents the statement from being accidentally true in that model (so it is true, but we just cannot see that)?

Further, if that question is even reasonable, what would then prevent statements from being accidentally independent (i.e., two models exist where P is true in one and false in the other, but we can't see that).

Comment: Is it possible that the reconstruction conjecture is false in every non-standard model, but true in the standard model? If so, we could argue that the standard model has some "accidental" properties.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this is what [constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) is all about! In [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), the law of excluded middle doesn't generally hold, so it is not always possible to derive $A$ (i.e. $A$ is true) from $\lnot\lnot A$ (i.e. $A$ is not false).

The particular case you're considering is a form of [Markov's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle), which can be worded as *if it is not the case that there is no example, then an example does exist*. Symbolically, the rule is $$\lnot\forall x\lnot A(x) \to \exists x A(x),$$ where $A(x)$ is required to be decidable: $\forall x(A(x) \lor \lnot A(x))$. In constructive mathematics, existence is very strong — it is not acceptable to merely show that there must be an example, one needs to actually produce an example in some way or another. Markov's principle says that showing that there must be an example is enough to prove existence. Thus this principle is not generally accepted by most schools of constructivism, except in limited instances.

Comment: What you describe is not Markov’s rule, but Markov’s principle. Markov’s rule is the corresponding derivation rule which states that when $\neg\forall x\neg A(x)$ is provable, then `$\exists x\,A(x)$` is provable (under appropriate conditions on $A$). All usual constructive theories (for example, Heyting arithmetic) *are* closed under this rule, even though they typically do not prove Markov’s principle. Therefore, even in constructive setting, it would suffice to prove that there is no counterexample in order to establish the conjecture.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 17):

I first encountered this kind of speculation in Chapter 3 of Richard Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, where Exercise 3(c) (or, in the second edition, Exercise 5(c)) suggests that if $f(n)$ is the number of non-isomorphic posets on $n$ elements, then the assertion that infinitely many $f(n)$ are palindromes in base ten is independent of the axioms of ZF. Clearly, this exercise is not intended to be tackled seriously; it's really an expression of the sentiment that there are some statements out there that are either true or false, but that we cannot hope to prove one way or another because they almost certainly lack the "structure" that we normally seek when doing mathematics.

If you want to try to formalize this notion, then one approach is to look at certain proofs of Gödel's incompleteness theorem.  For example, if you fix an axiomatic system such as ZF, then the theorems of the system are computably enumerable, but the set of arithmetical truths is not computably enumerable, so there must exist some truths that are not provable simply because (informally speaking) they are "too complicated to compute."  If you want to emphasize the idea that the unprovable statements are "complex" or "unstructured" in some sense, then you might prefer [Chaitin's proof of the incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Chaitin.27s_incompleteness_theorem), which shows that for any formal system $S$, there is a constant $L$ such that the statement "$K(s) > L$" is unprovable in $S$ for all strings $s$ (here $K$ denotes Kolmogorov complexity).  The vast majority of such statements are true "at random" because a random string will have high Kolmogorov complexity.

However, you might not be satisfied with the above approach, because your intuition about the graph reconstruction conjecture is *not* based on the idea that the *formal statement* of the conjecture is so complex or uncomputable that it cannot be proved.  The conjecture, after all, can be stated very simply.  It's the apparent lack of relevant structure in the *set of all graphs* that is causing trouble.

It might be helpful to specify more carefully what kinds of "true by accident" statements you are thinking of.  One approach would be to construct a heuristic *probabilistic model* that predicts that certain things ought to be true just for "random reasons."  For example, there is [Cramér's random model for the primes](https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=Cramer%27s_random_model_for_the_primes), which can be used to give heuristic "proofs" of various number-theoretic conjectures; e.g., one can use the model to predict that there will be only finitely many primes with such-and-such a property, because the probability that a prime $p$ has the property decreases rapidly to zero as $p\to\infty$.  It is easy to come up with many such conjectures that have a "true by accident" feel to them.  (In particular, I think it would be interesting if you could come up with a heuristic probabilistic model for graph theory, in the spirit of Cramér's model, that could "predict" various well-known graph-theoretic conjectures, including the reconstruction conjecture.)

The trouble with this approach is that there doesn't seem to be any clear way to declare that some particular statement of interest (such as the graph reconstruction conjecture) *doesn't* have a nice proof.  In a [related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27755/), Goldbach's conjecture is proposed as an example of something that might be "true by accident," but there's enough relevant structure that such a claim is highly controversial.  The space of all possible proofs is itself a highly complex mathematical object, so who is to say that the statement "Intractable-looking conjecture X has a simple proof" couldn't be "true by accident"?  Maybe there exists a beautifully simple proof out there, but it's a tiny needle buried in a totally unstructured haystack, and so we humans will never be able to find it.

In summary, there are some ways one could try to formalize this notion, but unfortunately, I don't think any of them lead in a promising direction (other than perhaps my suggestion above that it would be interesting to formulate a heuristic probabilistic model for graph theory that could "predict" the truth of certain conjectures without actually proving them).

---

**EDIT (August 2022):** I recently learned of John Conway's 2013 *Amer. Math. Monthly* article, [On unsettleable arithmetical problems](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.192), which among other things gives examples of probabilistic reasoning in support of a claim that some proposition is "unsettleable."  To give you the flavor, let me quote from Conway's Postscript:

> The following argument has convinced me
> that the Collatz $3n + 1$ Conjecture is itself very likely to be unsettleable, rather than
> this merely having the slight chance mentioned above. It uses the fact that there are
> arbitrarily tall “mountains” in the graph of the Collatz game. To see this, observe that
> $2m − 1$ passes in two moves to $3m − 1$, from which it follows that $2^k m − 1$ passes
> in $2k$ moves to $3^k m − 1$. Now by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we can arrange
> that $3^k m − 1$ has the form $2^l n$, which passes by $l$ moves to $n$. There is a very slight
> possibility that $n$ happens to be the same as the number $2^k m − 1$ that we started with.
> Let’s suppose that the starting number $2^k m − 1$ is about a googol; then the downward
> slope of the mountain certainly contains a number between one and two googols, so
> the chance that this is the same as the starting number is at least one googolth. (This
> is justified by observations for smaller $n$ showing that the first iterate that lies in the
> range $[n, 2n)$ is approximately uniformly distributed in this range.) In my view the
> fact that this probability, though very small, is positive, makes it extremely unlikely
> that there can be a proof that the Collatz game has no cycles that contain only large
> numbers. This should not be confused with a suggestion that there actually are cycles
> containing large numbers. After all, events whose probability is around one googolth
> are distinctly unlikely to happen!

**EDIT (February 2024):** Here's another potentially illuminating remark by Conway. Conway was convinced that some mathematical facts are definitely *not* "true by accident." As mentioned in the MO question [Why does the monster group exist?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453193) Conway said that the monster group is "obviously not there just by coincidence; it's got too many intriguing properties for it to all be just an accident." Note that there mere fact that the existence of the monster group had already been proved did not satisfy Conway; he did not feel that the proof answered the "why?" question. So at least for Conway, having a proof does not automatically guarantee that something is not "true by accident" (or in other words, being "true by accident" does not automatically mean that something is not provable).

Comment: The paper Conway: On unsettleable arithmetical problems is available on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.192), too. I tried to find a copy without paywall - I only found [this one](http://raganwald.com/assets/fractran/Conway-On-Unsettleable-Arithmetical-Problems.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

This is a take on this question of a form different from the other answers, along the lines of the comments of Gjergji Zaimi and André Henriques.

No doubt in present day mathematics there are some conjectures or perhaps even results that have an 'accidental' feel, while others do not have this feel.

However, it seems to me that to a certain and I believe considerable extent this is a subjective impression, or perhaps subjective is not really the right term and I should rather say, this impression is informed by the *current state* of mathematics.

I do not have really good and precise historical examples at hand, but I think it is true that for example certain results on diophantine equations (finiteness results of solutions, say) a long time ago had a much more accidental feel. But now with the developement of Arithmetic Geometry (eg Mordell conj.) some of them are much better and conceptually understood and *now* feel natural or at least not accidental anymore.

Perhaps some of the results and conjectures that *today* look accidental will at some point in the future be natural consequence of theories yet to be developped.
Indeed, I believe it to be a quite common pattern of progress in mathematics that developements begin with concrete and isolated results and questions, and then theories follow that explain the 'accidents' and 'miracles'.

Goldbach's conjecture got mentioned and gets mentioned frequently as accidental. Let us look at something not too far away.

The prime numbers contain infinitely many 3-term arithmetic progressions (van der Corput, 1930s). Accident, yes or no? Perhaps one could have thought so, when it was proved, but today the situation is different and it is widely conjectured (very recent results of Sanders achieve this for sets of just a slightly larger density) that *any* set of positive integers with the density of the primes has this property.

Who knows where the Theory of Set Addition (more generally Additive Combinatorics/Number Theory) will stand in some decades or centuries? Perhaps, then Goldbach conjecture will be a corollary of some natural theory.

In brief, I believe 'true by accident' (in the informal way I understand it, which seems not that far from the questioners intent) is to a considerable extent a time-dependent notion; it seems thus difficult for me to imagine that its spirit can be captured in a formal (time-independent) theory.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the OP's take on these things, but the way I read it, the fact that any set of positive integers with the density of the primes should have the same property is precisely the sort of "accident" the OP was talking about: given how ubiquitous the primes are, a suitable random model would tell you that the statement has a very low chance of failing. In other words, it is not true for a special reason, it is true because it has no reason to be false. 

Comment: Similarly with the Goldbach conjecture: there are so many primes that if Goldbach doesn't accidentally fail for some small number, then a probabilistic argument says that it has a very low chance of failing at all. This might not be a special property of the primes, but simply a property of a generic sufficiently dense set, and the fact that it doesn't accidentally fail for the primes is "luck".

Comment: @Alex: However, the OP also says that accidental truths *cannot be proved*.  This puts an additional spin on the topic.  I think quid is right that one's feeling of what sorts of things "cannot be proved" are informed mainly by one's sense of what *current* mathematical technology is or is not capable of achieving.

Comment: @Timothy Yes, I wasn't trying to address that part at all, since the wonderful answers already given address the provability issue very nicely. I was just joining quid in trying to understand what exactly the OP has in mind when he talks about accidents. What I am trying to say is that even though a theorem is provable, it can feel like it's true for no special reason other than the absence of a reason to be false. And the example quid gave seems to me to exemplify exactly this situation.

Comment: Yes, my main point is what Timothy Chow high-lighted. Perhaps, the illustrating ex. are not choosen optimal. Alex, regarding 3-AP my intent was to point out that the fact is completely *explained* by density. So, I would not say it is a 'no reason to be false' plus luck situation as *all* sets having this density (conjecturally) have the property. So one *knows* a reason why it is true. For Goldbach, first density cannot suffice but this is irrelevant, but second what I meant was that this super-advanced state of AC I dreamed-up *would* give a reason for what you refer to as 'luck'.

Comment: The above comment was written before Alex comment so let me highlight a point is view of it. Alex, it seems you misunderstand my point with 3-AP. There *is* a reason, the density, which suffices to *explain* the phenomenon. (It's not most sets and the primes happen to be one, it is *all* sets.) 

Comment: @quid: Agreed greatly with most of your answer; but I wouldn’t share the pessimism of your last paragraph.  Analogously, before the development of formal logic, someone might have said “‘Proven’ is a time-dependent notion; it seems thus difficult for me to imagine that its spirit can be captured in a formal theory.”  But now provability is formalised, and we can prove independence results which tell us things about the time-dependent notion of ‘proven’.  Surely some imaginative logician might yet come up with a formalisation which says something about this intuitive idea of ‘true by accident’?

Comment: Peter, thinking about it, I agree with your assertion; since I am so speculative in an optimistic way in others parts, I should have been consistent and phrased this less absolutely. 

Comment: "it is true because it has no reason to be false." Zagier had a similar comment, say about why $\pi$ is normal; if it *isn't*, there must be some deep reason, but if it is normal, the reason is just that it's random. For the other part, you can model many things by random sense (like $\mu(n)$ as random $0,\pm 1$ coefficients of a Dirichlet series, for RH, or Cramer's model of primes, for gaps), and the question should be whether the general randomness persists in the problem at hand. Another similar is Goldbach (partitio numerorum for general) as said.

Comment: Junkie, thank you for the examples. In particular, the quote on $\pi$, which I in principle knew but forgot. Let us look a bit more than a century back on the *transcendence* of certain numbers (not pi itself, but in Hilbert 7th problem). Perhaps somebody could have said...since there would need to be a reason for them to be algebraic, and there is not, they will be transcendental, but no proof in sight (if I remeber well Hilbert was quite pessimistic in his prediction when 7th prob. would be solved.) Yet, 'suddenly' came Gelfond--Schneider and a 'reason' for transcendence of these numbers.

Comment: It seems entirely possible that the Twin Prime Conjecture might be something that just happens to be true.

Comment: Junkie wrote: "... if [π] is normal, the reason is just that it's random." But what does the word "random" mean here?

Answer (score 10):

The statement in question can be formalized in the language of Peano Arithmetic, and I will treat it as a statement in that language.  A similar analysis works for any effective theory stronger than PA, such as ZFC.

Consider the set of all sentences in the language of PA; define an order relation $R$ so that $\phi \mathbin{R} \psi$ if $\phi \to \psi$ is provable in PA. This gives a pre-order; if we perform the usual equivalence class construction then the resulting algebra is a partial order called a Lindenbaum algebra (*).

Because the graph reconstruction conjecture corresponds to a sentence $G$ in PA, it corresponds to a particular node in this algebra.

- If $G$ is provable in PA, then $G$ corresponds to the bottom element of the algebra
- If $G$ is false, it corresponds to the top node of the algebra, but in this case we're not very worried about its provability
- Otherwise, $G$ corresponds to some intermediate node of the algebra. In that case, we cannot prove $G$ from PA, but we can prove $G$ by assuming PA plus any axiom either in the equivalence class of sentences that forms $G$'s node or in the equivalence class of any node higher than $G$'s node.

In every case, unless $G$ is false, $G$ is amenable to proof, but the proof will have to assume axioms that are strong enough to prove the desired conclusion. There is no sentence which could "never actually be proved", although there are plenty of sentences that cannot be proved in PA, and false sentences can only be proved from false axioms. The question is simply which axioms are required to prove a particular sentence.

---

*: Traditionally, a "Lindenbaum algebra" or "Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra" should be defined with the dual ordering of the ordering I use. But the ordering in which $0=1$ corresponds to the top of the algebra matches better with the diagrams we create to illustrate relationships between different axiom systems, such as [1](https://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu/). People also use the reverse ordering in the context of set theory, where large cardinal axioms are sorted by consistency strength, e.g. [2](http://websupport1.citytech.cuny.edu/faculty/vgitman/images/diagram.jpg).

Comment: (I think you mean '≥' and not '>'.)

Comment: For the usual definition of the Lindenbaum algebra, you would mean neither `$>$` nor $\geq$ but $\leq$.  But your use of "bottom", "top", and "higher" indicates that you really intend $\geq$ and thus the dual of the usual definition.  

Comment: I do mean the algebra which puts $0=1$ at the top. I was only using '$>$' as an arbitrary relation symbol. I changed it to an $R$ to avoid entirely any confusion about whether it should have a horizontal line. 

Comment: (The reason for making falsity the bottom in the standard definition is, of course, that once you really treat it as an algebra rather than just order, it is quite inconvenient to have $[\phi]\land[\psi]=[\phi\lor\psi]$ and $[\phi]\lor[\psi]=[\phi\land\psi]$, where $[\phi]$ denotes the equivalence class of a formula $\phi$.)

Comment: @Emil: Yes; it's just the order that is of interest here. The algebra itself is often uninteresting as an algebra, as you explained in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65851/lindenbaum-algebras-and-models/65853#65853 . The point of the diagrams I linked at the end of my answer is to show interesting suborders obtained by picking a few recognizable nodes out of the order. 

Comment: Is there a common name for what would traditionally have been called the dual of a Lindenbaum algebra? 

Comment: The first link seems to be dead and I did not find it [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~damir/files/diag_hs_2007.pdf) either. I browsed a bit [Damir D. Dzhafarov's new website](https://damir.math.uconn.edu/) but did not find it - maybe somebody else might have better luck.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak - I changed the link to https://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu/